# Logitech G5 side button is not generic

Tags: windows-7, mouse, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech G5. I have setpoint 6.30.41 with 5.30.67 driver installed on my windows 7 computer.

I want to use the side button (mouse4) to be a generic button. However, it acts like a back button in internet browsers and explorers. It's extremely annoying because I'm using this button for push to talk in teamspeak.

In the setpoint control panel, I have assigned generic button to the side button.

There are a couple of things I already tried:
I uninstalled setpoint, restarted the computer then installed the latest setpoint.
I reinstalled the microsoft intellitype in the similar fashion because i'm using a microsoft keyboard.

any help would be appreciated.

PS. I have looked the existing posts already. I think they are work-around. Non of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

SetPoint can sometimes use application-specific settings. Even if you've set a button to do one task in general, it might behave differently in certain applications (browsers, Microsoft Office). Open SetPoint and go here:

[image: SetPoint Screenshot 1]

and click on `Configure` to see this:

[image]

Try removing everything listed under `1. Select Application`. It might help.

Another alternative is to install [uberOptions](http://uberoptions.net/), which'll give you more custom options for each and every mouse button. (Note: Follow the instructions on the website carefully when installing on Windows 7).